# Using CMake generator expressions to link if target exists

Tags: cmake, generator-expression

I have this CMakeLists.txt snippet:

```
if (TARGET bar)
  target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC bar)
else()
  target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC baz)
endif()
```

I imagine I can make this shorter with CMake's generator expressions.  How would I do that?

I tried:

```
target_link_library(foo PUBLIC $<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:bar>,bar,baz> )
```

but in practice, `foo` doesn't appear link to either library.

Comment: In your `if()` snippet you use `PUBLIC` keyword, but in the snipper with regular expressions you use `INTERFACE` keyword. The latter keyword affects only on the **consumers** of the library, not on the library itself.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Good point, but unfortunately that isn't the problem.  My guess is that [conditional expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#conditional-expressions) like `$<IF:condition,true_string,false_string>` only work with strings and not with targets.

Comment: I have copy-pasted your attempt - `target_link_library(foo PUBLIC $<IF:$<TARGET_EXISTS:bar>,bar,baz> )` - into simple `CMakeLists.txt` and found it working: depending on existence of `bar` library target, it links either with `bar` or with `baz`. My CMake is 3.16.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I must have had a problem with refreshing my CMakeCache or somethig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar, but not identical logic that seems to work is:

```
target_link_library(foo PUBLIC
  $<TARGET_NAME_IF_EXISTS:bar>
  $<TARGET_NAME_IF_EXISTS:baz>
)
```